# Import data file stored on Wolfram Mathematica Online into Mathematica Desktop

Tags: import, mathematica-online

Is it possible to read a data file stored in a folder on Wolfram Mathematica Online into the desktop version of Mathematica?  If so, how is the location/url specified?

Comment: I recommend you post the answer part of your question as a self-answer. Then you are likely to get up-votes for both question and answer.

Comment: @m_goldberg, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Naturally I figured it out shortly after posting the question:

`CloudImport["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/UUID"]`

The UUID can be found by highlighting the file in Mathematica Online and choosing File Info from the dropdown menu.

Comment: Or you can just pass the path. Or use `CloudObject["user:your_id/relative/path/to/object"]`

Comment: @b3m2a1, thanks for the helpful tip.